# Adding variable to constant, php

Tags: php, variables, constants

I have defined a few constants like this:

```
define("TITLE_2","Yahoo");
define("TITLE_3","Google");
```

Next, I want to get the constant through a function.

```
public function title($id) {
    return TITLE_.$id;
}
```

Idea, I can call $this->title(2) to get Yahoo and $this->title(3) to get Google. However, it is not working. I am getting TITLE_2 or TITLE_3 in place of Yahoo or Google.

Help? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway? `TITLE_1` is as meaningless as `TITLE_2`. Passing 1 or 2 to `getTitle()` is not helping anyone to understand what these Magic Numbers stand for. Either you *want to* use Constants, then access them directly with `TITLE_YAHOO` or `TITLE_GOOGLE` or use Contant Methods *instead of* the Constants, e.g. `getTitleForYahoo()` and `getTitleForGoogle()` where those return the strings. But not that mishmash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function

```
public function title($id) {
    return constant("TITLE_$id");
}
```

Comment: TITLE_.$id should be quoted. otherwise PHP notice will be there.

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant TITLE_ - assumed 'TITLE_' in Command line code on line 1  --- You should use "TITLE_$id"

Answer (score 4):

What php is trying to do here is "get the define `TITLE_` and then append the value stored in $id".

You need to use the [`constant()`](http://de3.php.net/constant) function for this to work like you want:

```
public function title($id) {

    return constant("TITLE_$id");
}
```

Using the way you decribed also produces and

> Notice: Use of undefined constant TITLE_ - assumed 'TITLE_'

Make sure you have error reporting turned on and at least enabled `E_NOTICE` warnings as they will help you **a lot** when debugging things like this.

Answer (score 1):

you need to `return constant(TITLE_.$id)`

edited

```
you need to `return constant("TITLE_.$id")`
```

Thanks Gaurav

Comment: TITLE_.$id should be quoted. otherwise PHP notice will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the get_defined_constants() to get the list of the constants and then pick the one you want...